# Visual Studio 2012 not recognising nullable type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I have 2 nullable DateTimes, so subtracting them will result in a nullable TimeSpan. I want to call `.Value` on this.

[image]

However, the autocompletion drop-down list thinks that the type inside the brackets is a normal TimeSpan. `.Value` is not in the list, and when I use any of the suggestions, it doesn't compile. It does compile when I manually type `.Value`.

The same issue occurs if only one of the DateTimes are nullable. It also occurs if I add a `TimeSpan?` to a `DateTime?` resulting in a `DateTime?`. Intellisense thinks it is a `DateTime`.

Is this a problem with Visual Studio's intellisense? I am at update 3, I do not have ReSharper. Same issue on another computer.

**Edit**: to be clear, I am asking a question about why intellisense is suggesting the wrong type. I know what to write to make the code compile.

Comment: Weird, what happens when you cast is as Timespan ie. `(TimeSpan)(date1 - date2).`?

Comment: @JMK it does the casting last, so same behaviour. Do you mean to put the whole thing in brackets? `((TimeSpan?)(date1 - date2)).Value` works correctly.

Comment: Was asking just out of curiosity mainly, will be interested to know what it turns out to be :)

Comment: Does anyone have any older versions of Visual Studio to test this on?

Comment: Confirmed similar behavior on VS 2008: http://i.imgur.com/ABL45FQ.jpg

Comment: VS 2010 does this too with C# but VB works I noticed.

Comment: Under further inspection, my IntelliSense updated to reflect it's knowledge of the Value member of the Nullable type, but didn't suggest Value as being a valid member. In fact, it underlined it red until I compiled: http://i.imgur.com/Cwald42.jpg  Someone shine the Jon Skeet beacon

Comment: @glace same here, I can hover over `Value` and it gives me the documentation for it.

Comment: For me it works correctly in VS2010 Professional (probably because of ReSharper)

Comment: It worked fine for me. I am on VS ultimate 2012 version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3.(Source: about screen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed, IS gets this wrong and doesn't correctly infer that the result of the subtraction is a `Nullable<TimeSpan>`, it infers TimeSpan.  You can whack it over the head by writing it like this instead:

```
var span = date1 - date2;
span.
```

Now is *does* correctly infer the type of the *span* variable, you'll see HasValue in the auto-completion window.  This otherwise isn't slower at all at runtime so its a reasonable workaround.

Nothing you or we can do about the original oops, you can however file a feedback report at connect.microsoft.com.  Post a link so we can vote for it.

Comment: Thanks, here you go https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793983/intellisense-inferring-incorrect-type